# Multiple list items are responding to my hovering over only one list item

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

HTML:

```
<div id="top_nav_menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">the process</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">bull</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">forum</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#top_nav_menu ul
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 6;
    width: 94%;
    float: right;
}
#top_nav_menu li
{
    float: left;
    background-color: #d35400;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-left: 1%;
    padding-bottom: 2%;

    -webkit-transition: padding-bottom .5s;
    -moz-transition: padding-bottom .5s;
    -o-transition: padding-bottom .5s;
    -ms-transition: padding-bottom .5s;
    transition: padding-bottom .5s;

    padding-top: 100%;
    width: 31%;
    height: 100%;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
#top_nav_menu li:hover
{
    background-color: #e67e22;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-bottom: 3%;
}
```

For some reason, whenever my cursor overs a list item within a list, all of the list items react to my hovering over that one item. Is there any way I can make it so that only one list item performs the transition?

Comment: This code is working fine for me. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/screenmutt/N2Xry/)

Comment: works fine for me as well

Comment: Any possible, negative technical anomalies I can be facing that's raising my issue?